# Placeholder text padding in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I have a placeholder and I want to give padding to it. So far it's working in chrome but not in Firefox.

In **Chrome**
[image]

In **Firefox**

[image]

there is no padding applied

This is my css

```
 .form-control::placeholder {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
```

and for firefox

```
 .form-control::-moz-placeholder{
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide example of your HTML?

Comment: Hey it is solved. Solution is below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the input padding as well to achieve the same effect. It is also going to have padding for when the user inputs text into the text box and not sit against the left border.

```
.form-control {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```